# How to update to latest Java JRE 71?

Tags: package-management, java, oracle

I installed the java jre via my package manager and get this version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

But the current Java Update is 71, so I downloaded it from the 
[official website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html), but I don't know how to install the download and what exact file I should download. How do I do that? I use Ubuntu 14

Comment: Java 8u72 is available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: OpenJDK and Oracle JDK are two different things. While the latter is based on the former and while they always share the same major version number (in this case 8 or 1.8, depending on how you want to count) they receive different updates and follow different updates cycles and receive different minor version numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Oracle java from `ppa:webupd8team/java`, it is quite easy to update it manually.

Download JDK from oracle site and extract it to

```
/usr/lib/jvm/
```

You will need to rename `jdk1.8.0_72` to `java-8-oracle`.

Comment: You are writing about the `jdk`, but I don't want to develop anything currently but only need the `jre` to execute something. Does your answer then still work?

Comment: If you install it from that PPA, then you installed JDK. It includes JRE. So you can do it.

Comment: I added the whole jdk, as the jre is included anyway. I think that could reduce compatibility errors in case I need to use an jdk someday. It worked, thanks!